# How to get `scroll at bottom` and `scroll at top` of a list view of a Sencha Touch list view?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I want to code `lazy loading` for the list view so that I need to add the action for my controller that fired when user scrolls down to bottom of the list and when scrolls up to the top of the list.

How can I do that using Sencha Architect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use Architect, but what you need is get a ref of your list in controller, and attach an handler for the `scroll` event of the scroller object in the `initialize` event of the list:

**Controller**

```
config: {
    refs: {
        list: '...',
        ...
    },
    control: {
        list: {
            initialize: 'onListInit'
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
},
onListInit: function() {
    var scroller = this.getScrollable().getScroller();
    scroller.on('scrollstart', this.onNnListScrollStart, this);
    scroller.on('scrollend',   this.onNnListScrollEnd,   this);
},
onNnListScrollStart: function(scroller, x, y) {
    console.log('START SCROLL');
},

onNnListScrollEnd: function(scroller, x, y) {
    console.log('scroll x:'+x);
    console.log('scroll y:'+y);

    var bottom = scroller.maxPosition.y;
    var top    = scroller.minPosition.y;

    var isScrollUp   = scroller.dragDirection.y === -1;
    var isScrollDown = scroller.dragDirection.y === 1;

    if (bottom === y && isScrollDown) {
        console.log('BOTTOM');    
    }

    if (top === y && isScrollUp) {
        console.log('TOP');
    }

    console.log('END SCROLL');
},
...
```

A Sencha Architect sample project implementing this guide can be downloaded [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2013/android/sencha%20architect%20-%20catch%20scroll%20event.zip)

Comment: We can catch the `scroll` event now. How can we determine we are at the top/bottom of the list while scrolling?

Comment: check arguments in `onListScroll` callback. Please mark the answer as 'accepted' if it works

Comment: I'm willing to mark yours as accepted when I can do it. Please put more detail on handling the arguments in `onListScroll` callback. My OP asks for catching `on top` and `at bottom` events when scrolled

Comment: I've edited the example above.  The `y===0` is the top position of the list. If you want to know dimension and position of any Sencha component once rendered you can use `<your component>.element.getBox()`

Comment: Awesome! I'll try that. By the way, how can we know such argument list of the event `scroll`? I tried to look at http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.scroll.Scroller-method-on for `on()` method but failed to get the arguemnt list for `scroll`. How did you beautifully get it @Claudio Bertozzi?

Comment: The above `on()` document leads me to `addListener` at http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-addListener which recommends "... looking at the 'events' section of the documentation for the component you are working with"; that tells me to open Ext.view.List at http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List but there is no `scroll` event in the **Event** list there. I'm lost :(

Comment: I have updated your sample code to identify the top & bottom scroll values

Comment: read carefully: the `scroll` event is dispatched by the `scroller` object of the `scrollable` property. In List object there is a `getScroller()` method, and the documentation tells you: "Please look at the Ext.scroll.Scroller documentation for more example on how to use this." If you follow the `Ext.scroll.Scroller` link and read documentation you will find that: "..the Ext.Container.getScrollable method returns an instance of Ext.scroll.View", finally in "Ext.scroll.View" docs they tells you "99% of the time all you need to use in this class is getScroller." that gives you the right object

Comment: I'll check the reading again later to see how can we get the argument list of the `scroll` event

Comment: Thanks to your help I have coded it successfully here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2013/android/BigStore.zip (Sencha Architect project) The issue is the `scroll` event is fired a lots (about 10-20 times) for each scroll up or down, please see snapshoot http://i.imgur.com/URWXHzD.png. How can we catch the last one only?

Comment: the `scroller` object dispatch the `scroll` event and also (read the doc at "http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.scroll.Scroller") `scrollstart` and `scrollend` ones.